# Why is "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++" used when compiling Boost?

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm attempting to manually compile Boost on Ubuntu Linux 12.04. However, it seems to be attempting to cross-compile, even though I haven't told it to.

These are the commands I used:

```
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost
git checkout boost-1.60.0
git submodule init
git submodule update

cd tools/build/
./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 install --prefix=/usr/local/

cd ../../
sudo b2 -j12 --build-dir=/tmp/build_boost --build-type=complete toolset=gcc address-model=64 architecture=x86 threading=multi runtime-link=shared stage --layout=tagged
```

The last command fails, giving various compilation errors, all similar to the first one shown below:

```
gcc.compile.c++ /tmp/build_boost/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/error_code.
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’

    "arm-linux-gnueabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic -pthread -fPIC -m64  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK=1 -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "/tmp/build_boost/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/error_code.o" "libs/system/src/error_code.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ /tmp/build_boost/boost/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-arm/release/address-model-64/architecture-x86/threading-multi/error_code.o...
```

How do I make sure it uses the native g++ (for x86-64)?

Comment: Is it possible arm-enabled gcc is in your path? bjam will take whatever it finds.

Comment: I do have ARM enabled gcc 4.7 and 4.8 on my path, but they're both prefixed with "arm-linux-gnueabi-". Typing `which g++` leads to /usr/bin/g++, which is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/g++, which is itself a symlink to /usr/bin/g++-5, which is the x86-64 compiler I expected the build system to use :-(

Comment: bjam is a terrible thing. I believe, it finds your compiler by some arcane logic. You might need to create your own toolset in bjam configuration file and than specify this toolset as an argument.

Comment: I found the problem. My fault :-( But I agree with you, bjam is terrible. I had to use your idea about the the arm-enabled gcc being in my path to finally force it to spit out a useful error. I tried to see if there were --verbose flags, could have been useful here. Actually, just double-checked, and there is a --debug-configuration that could have pointed the problem out. Anyway, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem: there was a user-config.jam in my home directory (probably stored temporarily during cross-compile tests). I only found out because removing all `arm-linux-gnueabi-*` files from `/usr/bin/` led to the following error:

```
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/tools/gcc.jam:83: in gcc.init from module gcc                             
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: provided command 'arm-linux-gnueabi-g++' not found
error: initialized from /home/janito/user-config.jam:45
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using from module toolset
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1052: in using from module project-rules                          
/home/janito/user-config.jam:45: in modules.load from module user-config
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:249: in load-config from module build-system
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:389: in load-configuration-files from module build-system
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:524: in load from module build-system
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
/home/janito/boost/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
/home/janito/boost/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

At least the solution was simply to remove the ~/user-config.jam file.

Posting it as an answer so that it can be useful in the future if someone runs into the same situation.